# d3 easing functions for accelerated/decelerated motion

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What [easing functions](https://github.com/d3/d3-ease) have I to use for transitions to simulate an uniformly accelerated motion and an uniformly decelerated motion in D3?

Comment: A linear one???

Comment: `d3.easeQuad(t)` constant acceleration leads to an x=k*a^2 equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For constant acceleration, the easing should be a square exponent.

```
(t) => t * t
```

The built-in [d3easeQuad(t)](https://github.com/d3/d3-ease/blob/master/src/quad.js) is the one you want.

Edit: Did not see @rioV8's comment above. Sorry for the repetition,